# Which game is shown in this GIF featuring a quicktime fight sequence?

Tags: game-identification

As the title says what game is shown in this gif? It shows a character in a fight sequence and the player must press buttons at the exact right time in order to continue the fight.

[image: Animated GIF fight sequence]

Comment: Also google search by image did not work.

Comment: Huh. The GIF played at first, but it won't play again, even if I refresh the page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is [Dragon Age II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Age_II).

[image: Dragon Age II game cover]

The gif shows a rogue male Hawke killing a Qunari warrior. The video seems to be an amalgam of various gameplay shots, not one continuous one.

DA2 can be played on Xbox 360, PlayStation 3, Mac OS X and PC. The computer version is only available on [Origin](https://www.origin.com/en-us/store/buy/dragon-age-2/mac-pc-download/base-game/standard-edition).

Answer (score 9):

The guy in the gif appears to be [**Hawke**](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Hawke), the player character of [**Dragon Age 2**](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Age_II). More specifically, he looks like male rogue Hawke.

[image]
From left to right: Mage Hawke, Warrior Hawke, and Rogue Hawke.

Comment: You missed it just now.I accepted another, but still upvote.:p